# Regex to force dashes not working

Tags: jquery, regex

I'm attempting to format a number as follows: `123456-12-1234`:

```
$('.telnumber').keyup(function() {
  var foo = $(this).val().split("-").join(""); // remove hyphens
  foo = foo.match(new RegExp('.{1,4}$|.{1,2}$|.{1,6}', 'g')).join("-");
  $(this).val(foo);
});
```

However it's not working as I'd expect - I just get chunks of 6: http://jsfiddle.net/juspC/892/

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you provide more info? What is sample input and what is expected output? You say "force dashes" but then the first thing I see you do is remove dashes, so I'm confused.

Comment: @dman2306 - As I type `123456121234`, I'd expect `123456-12-1234`.  JSFiddle demonstrates what I'm seeing now.  I remove dashes so that I can re-eval on keyup.

Comment: The reason is the `|` will always match the longest of the options. Why even use regex? Seems to me something like a simple `substring` would take care of this very simply. Grab the first 6 chars, the next 2, and the next 4. Put - between them. Also as an FYI, you're not doing anything to force numbers, so *&^&*$#^&*$^#&*^$# would work, and also keyup does not fire if someone pastes, or drags text into the field.

Comment: @dman2306 thanks - I chose regex so I wouldn't have to worry about null/length checking around `substring`.  Thanks for the heads up on the other things - this was intentionally dumbed down so the only code seen is the regex that I'm struggling with.

Comment: `|` doesn't cause longest to match but first successful match in alternation satisfies engine. @dman2306

Comment: Without infinite width lookbehinds, you can't do it with one regex.

Comment: Please add more and different input / output examples.

Comment: @revo I don't know if that will help much.  The requirement is simple - turn `123456121234` into `123456-12-1234` as I type.  `6` characters, then a dash, then `2` characters, then a dash, then `4` characters.

Comment: @revo sorry you're right, I was just doing work today with a POSIX regex library which does longest matches for alternation. My bad.

Comment: Let me know its name. @dman2306

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can support IE9+ I would recommend using the [`input` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input).  If that's not the case, you should use a library.  [Input Mask](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask) looks pretty good.

```js
$('form input').on('input', function(e) {
  // get just the number
  var numeric = this.value.replace(/-/g, '');
  // split it by number of numeric characters
  split = numeric.match(/^(\d{0,6})(\d{0,2})(\d{0,4})/);
  // shift off the whole match
  split.shift();
  // join back up using dashes and trim trailing and leading dashes
  this.value = split.join('-').replace(/^\-+|\-+$/, '');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type='text' maxlength="14"/>
</form>
```

Edit: if you want to get all ES6 on this thing, you can also do the following for line 9 instead of the odd regex replace.

```
this.value = split.filter(a=>a).join('-');
```

Comment: If you need IE8 as well, the MS event `propertychange` provides the same information as long as you look at `e.originalEvent.propertyName == "value"`

Comment: @dman2306 Nice! and it plays nicely with you changing the value inside of the event listener?  Does it hit an infinite loop?

Comment: No,  you'd need to add your own code to prevent the infinite loop unfortunately. It's not pretty, but if you need IE8 support, it's pretty much the only thing that covers all cases.